# How to get multiple canvas tags to render reliably in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-canvas

Has anyone had problems with Google Chrome not rendering canvas tags when more than one canvas is used on a page?

I've been having this happen. It occurs in some of my pages, but not others; I'm having a hard time isolating the critical element. When the problem does occur, the behavior is consistent: a particular set of canvas tags (sometimes all canvases on the page) don't render -- they appear as whitespace. It occurs reliably in Chrome / Mac, but does not occur in Firefox / Mac. Interestingly, if I right-click on one of the blank canvases and choose Inspect Element, then suddenly all of the canvases appear. So it really looks like a Chrome bug, as opposed to some error in my code.

The problem can be observed by clicking "Run" in this jsfiddle file:

http://jsfiddle.net/9HbWV/

This page contains two canvas tags, and a script block that draws a rectangle in one of them. In Chrome, the rectangle does not appear. If you un-comment out the last line and re-run, the rectangle does appear. That last line simply invokes getContext() on the other canvas.

I have other, more complex examples where some canvases don't render even if getContext() is called for each canvas. So the problem is not as simple as "getContext must be called at least once for each canvas".

Comment: It isn't uncommenting that makes it work. Try simply hitting run, without changing anything. It magically works now.

Comment: Hmm, not for me. I can hit Run repeatedly (in the original state, with the last line commented out) and the rectangle never appears. Did the problem reproduce for you at all?

Comment: Nope. It randomly starts appearing if I keep clicking run. Version of Chrome: `22.0.1229.12 (Official Build 152477) dev`

Comment: I think this might be a JSFiddle bug. I've had several projects use multiple canvases (over each other), and they work perfectly in Chrome.

Comment: It's definitely not specific to JSFiddle. I originally observed it in a Tomcat app and have reproduced it in a trivial static file on the Tomcat server. Chrome 21.0.1180.82 here.

Comment: Maybe what I'm seeing is a JSFiddle bug, and yours is a Chrome, version specific bug. Try submitting it to http://crbug.com

Comment: Thanks, I've done that: [link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=144686)

Comment: Definetly not a bug in JsFiddle. I can reproduce this on Chrome and IE9. I will try the workaround below

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: the discussion of the Chrome bug report (linked below) reveals a workaround: attach a unique CSS class to each canvas. I.e.

<canvas id="A" width=400 height=400 class=canvasA></canvas>
<canvas id='B' width=400 height=400 class=canvasB></canvas>​

---

Turns out this is in fact a bug in Chrome: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=144686. A couple of details emerge from the bug comments:

1. You can work around the bug by going to about:flags and activating the "Disable accelerated 2D canvas" option.
2. Small canvases (e.g. 200 x 200) do not appear to exhibit the problem, because the problem seems to be GPU-related and Chrome does not attempt to use the GPU for small canvases.