# Canvas issues with Chrome on Mac

Tags: javascript, macos, html, google-chrome

I've been looking for a long time for the reason why the drawing, erasing and redrawing of a rotated rectangle on the canvas element does not work in google chrome on mac.

I need this because i want to render a hover overlay on the canvas.

I've created a Fiddle that represents my code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/z8f2f/23/)

Html:

```
<canvas id="canvas"  width="400" height="165" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; background-color:red;"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas =null;
var ctx;
var target;

$(function() {
        canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        target = { h:81, id:"i1_2", isempty:false, r:-11.64, w:60, x:143, y:19, zindex:2};
});

function drawRectangle() {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(target.x, target.y);
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "blue";
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.40;
        ctx.rotate(target.r / 180 * Math.PI); //NO Rotation => It works!
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,target.w,target.h);
        ctx.restore();   
}

function clearRectangle() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,165);
}
```

This works fine in all browsers on windows and mac except for Chrome on Mac.

When i comment out the line

```
// ctx.rotate(angle);
```

The rectangle is drawn on the canvas. (without rotation of course)

Did I do something wrong? Or is this maybe a bug in Chrome?

Edit: Probably not a bug in Chrome because this test page works in chrome on Mac:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/advanced/html5_canvas_transform_rotate/

Edit 2: I've been doing some more research on this and i found this issue logged: [link](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=129732)

I took there test fiddle and added some more tests with rotates canvas elements: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Dz4BJ/17/)
Reading there info, the problem is "solved" when you draw on a smaller canvas.

See here my results of the fiddle:
[image: Bad results]

When I change the sizes of the canvases in the above fiddle, making them just 1pixel smaller. Then the results are ok.

[image: Good results]

Final conclusion: It seems I can draw a rotated rectangle once. But when i use the clearRect method to erase the canvas, I cannot draw the rectangle again. This only happens when the size of the canvas is big enough. (Bigger than  65600px)

Does anyone of you knows a sollution for this so i can draw and redraw rectangles on the canvas using chrome on mac?

I'm getting crazy about this.

Comment: Make a http://jsfiddle.net and you might get more help.

Comment: This is my current Fiddle, It's not yet what i want because it has some strange behaviour also in other browsers. I'll work more on it as soon as i can.

Comment: What is? (you didn't post a link...)

Comment: Updated question with more info. Yeah, i forgot the link on Friday :s

Comment: Please take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12440283.
It might solve your problem


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12440283

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at my question. Unfortunatly, adding a class to each canvas in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dz4BJ/18/ still returns the same results. I've also tested it in my environment (where there is only one canvas) with the same results.

Comment: What mac/version of chrome? I'm loading the JS fiddle on a 2010 mac pro in Chrome 22 and I can render the rotated rectangle just fine in the JSfiddle example...

Comment: It's a Max OSx 10.6.8 with Chrome 22.0.1229.79. What fiddle are you talking about? http://jsfiddle.net/Dz4BJ/17/ or http://jsfiddle.net/z8f2f/23/ ? in the first one you need to see 4 canvases with 8 squares in each of them. In the second one you need to check if you can draw, erase and redraw the rotated rectangle. Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Mac 10.6.8/Chrome 22.0.1229.79. Both fiddles work for me. (jsfiddle.net/Dz4BJ/17/ and jsfiddle.net/z8f2f/23/)

Comment: Both work for me on OS X 10.8.2, Chrome 22.0.1229.79

Comment: Worked fine on OS X 10.8.2, Chrome 24.0.1290.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the research you've done you're already aware this is a browser bug, so you can't fix it yourself per se. You can, however, work around the problem by using smaller canvases adjacent to each other and drawing on each one with a different offset so the edges of your shapes are aligned.

It's not exactly nice from the point of view of the code, but visually it will look the same and it should work around the bug.

I've modified your fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/z8f2f/35/

Comment: This is a little bit hard to implement in my environment but i think it might come handy in the future. If it's working on most versions then i think it's not a big problem for my visitors. Thanks for the workaround. That was indeed something i was looking for.